# Error handler raising an exception (Type Error) on discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, bots, discord.py

I'm currently trying to handle errors in my discord bot clear command. My code is as follows:

```
@commands.command(name='clear', aliases=['clean', 'cleanup'])
@commands.guild_only()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def clear(self, ctx, message, limit: int = 10) -> None:
        await ctx.message.add_reaction("<:tars_certo:783051315764133910>")
        time.sleep(2)
        messages = await ctx.channel.purge(bulk=True, limit=limit)
        embed=discord.Embed(title=f"`{len(messages)}` mensagens deletadas com sucesso", color=COR_PRINCIPAL)
        embed.set_author(name="Plugin de comandos do TARS",icon_url=ICONE)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=5)

@clear.error
async def clear_error(ctx, error):
  if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
        embed=discord.Embed(title="<:tars_x:783051246776877057> Erro: Você não tem permissão para usar este comando", color=COR_PRINCIPAL)
        embed.set_author(name="TARS help",icon_url=ICONE)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

But, for some reason, I received the current error:

```
Command raised an exception: TypeError: clear_error() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

This is the full error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 851, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 778, in prepare
    if not await self.can_run(ctx):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 1076, in can_run
    return await discord.utils.async_all(predicate(ctx) for predicate in predicates)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/utils.py", line 338, in async_all
    for elem in gen:
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 1076, in <genexpr>
    return await discord.utils.async_all(predicate(ctx) for predicate in predicates)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 1769, in predicate
    raise MissingPermissions(missing)
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingPermissions: You are missing Manage Messages permission(s) to run this command.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 71, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: clear_error() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 333, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 943, in on_message
    await self.process_commands(message)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 940, in process_commands
    await self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 907, in invoke
    await ctx.command.dispatch_error(ctx, exc)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 422, in dispatch_error
    await injected(cog, ctx, error)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 77, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: clear_error() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `self` on `async def clear_error(ctx, error):`